# UIImageView partial opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, opacity

#### Situation

I have a `UIView`( light gray colored ) and a `UIImageView` as a subview of the view.

The Image View would move and rotate by changing its frame or using `CGAffineTransform`.  Part or entire Image View might go beyond the parent View( the light gray one )

#### Problem

I need to make the ImageView opaque where it’s not over the parent view( light gray one ).

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You need to make something for your background image, either fill background color etc.

Comment: Does the image view need to be a subview of the UIView?

Comment: Yes, the ImageView should be a subview of the UIView.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for.  Show us your expected result.

Comment: I updated the image on my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this   view.clipsTobounds = NO;